# What is on the back of a stormtrooper's armor?

Tags: star-wars

What do the letters/symbols on the back of a stormtrooper's armor represent or stand for? As the image below shows, it looks like a zero and two ones, or the letter O and two lines? I originally thought it said "OIL", but that seems silly.

[image]

Comment: Looks like *Record* and *Pause*.

Comment: BWAHAHAHA! I've been watching Star Wars for years and never thought that 'till *just now*...

Comment: The cast and crew referred to it as "donuts and Twinkies".

Comment: I always thought it was "OIL" as a kid also.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/118212/4918 "Why are stormtroopers' legs asymmetrical?" about other features of the stormtrooper armor.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Stormtrooper armor was sectional, and when removed, you could access the inside of each piece.  I believe the segment [you are looking at](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_armor#Utility_belt_and_backpack) covers the emergency air supply and some of the power/electronic equipment. (It's listed as the 'Backplate'.)  Those aren't meant to be markings (Rank markings were indicated by a colored pauldron), but instead protrusions due to having to accommodate what was underneath of them.

Incidentally, the tube below is a custom [thermal detonator](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thermal_detonator#Types), with a secret trigger code known only to the individual trooper. (Star Wars Official Fact file, volume 4.)

Most of this information comes from [*Star Wars: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visual_Dictionary), as referenced by [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: I've heard (probably just a rumor) that it was a deliberate joke, intended to look like the `0` and `1` of an on/off switch.  This is obviously not an in-universe explanation.

Comment: Incidentally, Wookipedia also mentions that "There are several anecdotes about the armor itself known to the film crews. The molded plastic back plate has two bars and a circular impression, comically called the "twinkies and donut" as if the backpack was an emergency food storage unit." but I don't see any source for this, so YMMV.