# Why are stormtroopers' legs asymmetrical?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

I'm curious why stormtroopers have a gear-like ending to their right upper leg piece, but on the left leg have a diamond shape over their knee.

Is there an in-universe explanation? (Or, if not, an out-of-universe one?)

[image: stormtroopers with their knee armor showing]

Comment: For some reason I visualized a scene where stormtroopers dropped to one knee to make better shots (better stability or cover?). Can't place it, so take with a grain of salt.  I think the knee armor arrangement would work for that - a stable base to kneel on on one side, if that was useful in a situation, and whatever advantage offered by the gear (or disadvantage offset, maybe better protection?) on the other.

Comment: So they can kneel comfortably.

Comment: Yeah...sorry about that.  The truth is, when I was designing the first prototype for their armor, right when I had just gotten to the right knee, my hand slipped and I accidentally cut right through it!  But luckily I was able to make it look okay using some bubblegum, hydrochloric acid, and SpaceGlue.

Comment: @Megha - I think you're close to an answer. Most military weapons are designed to be fired with the right hand on the grip, using the right eye to aim. Real-world training for kneeling stance has the soldier drop to his left knee and rest his right elbow on his right left for added stability. This explains the left knee design of the armor - not sure what advantage the right knee offers...

Comment: So stormtroopers could tell left from right?

Comment: @HorusKol They're often depicted turning corners in a synchronised fashion, so yes.

Comment: @Horus Where exactly on the body (in particular, on which side of the body) is the right left situated? ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - yes, I saw that after the time limit expired... :(

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Precisely in the middle. =P

Comment: Downvote: No hand-drawn circles.

Comment: a better question is are they wearing slippers or white Italian leather shoes?

Comment: @Skooba - If I remember right, they were white disco boots. If you go Googling around for Stormtrooper boots, you'll often find them labeled as Stormtrooper Elvis Disco Boots or something similar which always makes me chuckle.

Answer (score 46):

The Star Wars Visual Dictionary tells us the answer:

[image: large]

[image: closeup]

The left knee plate is a **"Sniper position knee protector plate"** and the ridges on the right thigh are **"Suit systems power cells."**

The [Legends entry on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_armor/Legends) backs this up, citing *Star Wars: Imperial Handbook: A Commander's Guide* as their source:

> - The lower right leg segment contained the suit's axillary power cells.
> - The left upper side of the shin armor had a knee protector plate for comfort from a kneeling firing position.

Comment: The first things to hit the ground when you fall are your knees, so logically this is where you'd store the suit's auxiliary power cells.

Comment: Haha, not a good design decision, huh?

Comment: @Daft I guess they all fall on their left knee.

Comment: Ahem - http://i.stack.imgur.com/bDIHL.png

Comment: Somehow stormtrooper and sniping does not click together in my mind.

Comment: Not a Starwars follower. It seems rather silly to put the systems power cells right in front where there is a higher chance of them getting damaged. Wouldn't it be better to place the cells on the back side of the suit?

Comment: @flq They're supposedly really good shots when they're not aiming at main characters. Remember the first time we see them? They wipe out a squad of rebels with ease

Comment: Um, standard kneeling position for all soldiers, especially snipers, is down on the right knee, for stability and accuracy purposes. Also, nice blaster holster XD

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - Well, that's assuming a dominant right hand.  Since this is a galaxy far away, perhaps left is the more common.  And, of course, since so many of the early Storm Troopers were clones, perhaps the clone was left handed, and they just stuck to his standard.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHfLyMAHrQE You're actually right. I've found that, in the original trilogy, stormtroopers are trained (or maybe just naturally inclined) to fire left-handed. You can clearly see they're all using their right hand to support the weapon while having their left hand on the trigger. I guess we'll have to ignore the fact that Jango, Boba and all the clone troopers in the prequel trilogy and clone wars series were all right-handed XD

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, the sniper plate on the left knee is attached to the left shin piece.  The "gear-like" piece is actually attached to the right thigh piece, not to the shin piece.

It is not specifically for kneeling on, though.  In the firing position, the left leg is forward and the right leg is back.  Because the left leg is forward, if the plate were not there, you would see a gap between the thigh and the shin plates that would be a weak point.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly hypothetical, so take with a grain of salt.

If you kneel while shooting, you'll kneel on the  knee at the same side of your dominant hand. To have better balance.

But that would require them to be all left handed and never to cover something on their left.

But it could be as well just be an artistic choice and backwards rationalization ( [see](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/118285/64436) pictures )

Comment: Is there support for this?

Comment: My military training, no hard evidence. If that´s it you are after =)

Comment: If you do a a google n image search for "kneeling shooting position", just about every picture you see features a right-handed shooter kneeling on his right knee and resting his left elbow on his right knee.  So it seems that the flat knee pad would be more beneficial for a left-handed shooter.

Comment: left right mixup , sry

Answer (score 0):

I have two theories to why the armour is asymmetrical.

1. Storm Troopers would shoot with their right knee to the ground.The pad was designed to protect the left knee from blaster fire when in shooting position.
2. The lack of a protection pad on the right knee would make getting into shooting position much easier and quicker.